# SQL Server 2008 R2 and Port 61303

Tags: sql, sql-server, port

I am running a database server and I was getting the infamous error 40 when trying to reach the server database from my client.  I couldn't fix it until I opened the inbound port 61303 on the server.  I searched everywhere and couldn't find any information about it.

Can anyone please tell me what would be running on this port or why my SSMS client is communicating on this port?  Is it safe to allow this inbound port through my firewall on the SQL server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you accessing the default instance or a named instance?  If it is the default instance, there is a chance that it was set up to use a different port than the default 1433 port.  If it is a named instance, then the SQL Browser service is accessed over port 1434 (by default) and dynamically allocates a port and the client will then access the instance through that port.

A named instance will have a dynamic port allocated.  That can get tricky with strict firewall rules.  You can configured SQL Server to instead of using dynamic ports to use a static or fixed port.  [Here is now to configure SQL Server to use fixed ports for named instances](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345327.aspx).  This will ensure that you'll know what port your named instance will be accessed through, and allow you to configure the firewall appropriately.